# Release SAP HANA Table Variable Memory

Tags: sql, hana

We have a scenario where we create table variables in the Stored Procedure for modularity purposes. But once the table variable is computed, we wanted to release the memory locked by the table variable.

So, lets say the code is something  like this

```
Temp_table_1 = select * from table;
Temp_table_2 = select <functionality 2> from :Temp_table_1;
```

I am doing this statement finally, but it doesn’t release the memory.

```
Temp_table_1 = select * from : Temp_table_1 where 1 = 0;
```

Memory is released only when the SP finishes.

Do you know any mechanism by which we can release the memory of these table variables during the processing of the stored procedure and not wait till the end of the procedure?